# update a record programmatically in adf, without any key reference

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am trying to programatically modify a record without any key reference, in screen it shows the modified value, but in table record is not modified

I stuck there please suggest

I have included the code below.

```
public String modifybank() {
    String st=""+soc3.getValue();
    System.out.println(st);
    String bname=""+soc4.getValue();
    String acno=""+it7.getValue();
    String amDef = "model.AppModule";
    String config = "AppModuleLocal";
    ApplicationModule ami =
        Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(amDef, config);
    AppModuleImpl am = (AppModuleImpl)ami;
    ViewObjectImpl demo1 =am.getCmbBankdetailsModifyView1();
    DCBindingContainer bindings1 =
        (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding branchItem;
    branchItem =
        (DCIteratorBinding)bindings1.get("CmbBankdetailsModifyView1Iterator");
    Row r2 = branchItem.getCurrentRow();
    System.out.println("acc"+r2.getAttribute("Accountno"));
    r2.setAttribute("Accountno", acno);
    r2.setAttribute("Bankname", bname);
    r2.setAttribute("Status", st);
    //demo1.insertRow(currentRow);
    am.getDBTransaction().commit();
    //branchItem.
    branchItem.executeQuery();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if i didn't understand your question properly... In iterator your changes appear, but you dont see them in UI component (table or list)?

Comment: in my local db @vssk

Comment: Did your check for some kind of errors in the log?

Comment: No error or warning @vssk

Comment: Try to change log level

Comment: Sry i am fresher, How can i change log level in jdeveloper11.1.1.7.1 @vssk

Comment: Read 31.5.3 from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/web_testdebug.htm#ADFFD21863)

Answer (score 2):

First, Dont update `Row` in `ManagedBean` class. Create a method in `AMImpl` and expose it as a `ClientInterface`. Then in `ManagedBean`

```
DCBindingContainer bindingContainer =
            (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
DCDataControl dc =
        bindingContainer.findDataControl("YourDataControl");
YourApplicationModuleImpl am = (YourApplicationModuleImpl)dc.getDataProvider();

am.yourClientInterfaceMethod();
```

Within your `YourApplicationModuleImpl`

```
yourClientInterfaceMethod() {
    // Get the row and update it and commit
    // You will have Getter method for your ViewObject in the same class
}
```